# Error installing symfony2 vendors locally with composer

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I hope I have phrased that correctly, but I am trying to install vendors into my symfony2 project, which I have just downloaded from SVN, but I keep getting this error,

```
  [Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]                                                                        
  Cannot import resource "parameters.ini" from "/Users/john/Sites/trunk/awesome/app/zone/config/../../config/config.yml".  

  [InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                 
  The file "parameters.ini" does not exist (in: /Users/john/Sites/trunk/awesome/app/zone/config/../../config, ).  

Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception

  [RuntimeException]                                                         
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.
```

Obviously it seems to be looking in the wrong directory, but I am not sure what file is pointing to those files.

Also, I am quite new to Symfony, so I am unsure of where to look to start fixing the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you have something like this into `app/config/config.yml`

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.ini }
```

And you haven't `parameters.ini` file

The `parameters.ini` file is used into Symfony 2.0 and now, in Symfony 2.1 (if you use composer,I suppose that you use Symfony 2.1) this file in turned into `parameters.yml` so please check for this "error" and try again

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `parameters.ini` file wasn't put into your repository as it stores sensitive data (like database password).

You should create it locally. Some people put template files into the repository, so look for files named like `parameters.ini.dist`. If there's no such file grab [the original file from symfony standard edition](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.0/app/config/parameters.ini) and adapt it to your environment.

As others pointed out, Symfony 2.1 uses `parameters.yml` instead of `parameters.ini` **by default**. You can still use ini file if you want though. If you have a `parameters.yml` file or want to start using it, follow instructions given in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by deleting the `vendor` directory and ran `composer install` again.